# URL encoding. Very difficult

Tags: php, html, line-breaks

I have a Japanese string like this (got from database)

$myString = "いっぱい< br />んどん"

Because the API requires the input string must be URL-encoded, so I encode it using

urlencode($myString);

**The problem is the API platform page shows that string in a textarea.**

As you know, the HTML texarea doesn't allow a line break using HTML < br />. It only allows "& #10;" to show a line break.

So now **I don't know how to show $myString in the textarea of API platform**.

My working flow: My website -> pass $myString to API -> $myString shows in API platform page (not mine)

**Update:**

The API is like this

```
< a href="diary:self?guid=ON&url=http%3A%2F%2Fredirect_uri.com&subject=%83e%83X%83g&body=....">Something< /a>
```

I have to pass myString to body=...

**Update:**

This is what I tried:

```
function convertBrTagtoASCII($string) {
    $string = str_replace(array("</br>", "</br >", "<br>", "<br >"), "&#10;", $string);
    return $string;
}

$converted = convertBrTagtoASCII($myString);
```

Replace all br tag with & #10;, then urlencode($converted), then pass to "body" param of the API link.
The output in textarea is

```
いっぱい&#10;んどん
```

It seems that the platform not only urldecode but also escapes the string. :(

Comment: Can't you just use some sort of regular expression transform to turn all `"< br />"` in the urlencoded result into `"&#10"`'s?  EDIT: Or you don't have control over the platform page.  In that case, can you do the transform before it's submitted to the `urlencode` function?

Comment: $myString = "いっぱい".'\n'."んどん";

Comment: Also, you can use "\n" in textareas, so you could use str_replace(); to replace "<br />" with "\n"

Comment: @zebedia49: If I urlencode mystring first, I can't preg_replace the < br > with &#10 because that tag is changed.

Comment: @Lex: in Chrome, \n doesn't print a line break in textarea. Try yourself >> <textarea>test\n\ntest</textarea>

Comment: Hm, you're right. Depends a bit on how it's implemented. If you have an \n in a double quoted string in PHP and echo that in a textarea it will work. But you're right, if you just add is as plain text or single quoted string it will just show \n

Answer (score 1):

Use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to escape special HTML characters, such as `<`.

```
echo '<textarea>'.htmlentities($myString).'</textarea>'
```

In a textarea element you can use newlines, so there is no need to do special escaping on those.

Edit: Maybe I misunderstood the problem and you already have `<br>` tags in your database. In that case, you can replace these tags with newlines. An alternative is to use a rich text edit box, such as [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), which does support HTML editing.

Comment: the problem is the textarea is not mine (it's API page), I can't do anything with that page.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an **encoding** problem, you have an **invalid data** problem. The string you want to send to the API is not valid in the context of the API. You'd have the same problem with `"Hello<br />World"`.

There are three possibilities:

- The string should be `"Hello&lt;br /&gt;World"` or `"いっぱい&lt; br /&gt;んどん"`, in this case you could simply repair it (and its cousins) with
- The string should be `"Hello\nWorld"` or `"いっぱい\nんどん"`, in this case you would need a regex or similar tool to fix it up before urlencoding.
- The string is really malformed: In this case you should reject both: `"Hello<br />World"` and `"いっぱい< br />;んどん"`

The main point ist, that this is not a property of the encoding or your code: Yes, you can try to fix obvious defects, but no there is no golden Rule

Comment: Do you mean $mystring is invalid? That string is stored in database, I just get it from that. The database is owned by customer. :S

Comment: Yes, I mean either $mystring is invalid, or the API specs are incomplete. I guessed, that the database is owned by customer, but that alone doesn't make all values valid ...

Answer (score 0):

Convert your breaks to ascii. Then encode the URL.
Then run a regex replace to convert the encoded line breaks

```
%26%2310%3B
```

back to

```
&#10;
```

Comment: That string is displayed by platform. I just pass it. So I don't have permission to preg_replace as you said.